# How to declare array in array in swagger yaml

Tags: arrays, yaml, swagger

I would like to declare array in array in swagger, but not sure how to do it:
e.g. I have case, with below parameters:

```
       "cells": [
           [
               {
                   "field": "testID",
                   "name": "testId",
                   "width": "74px",
                   "sortable": true
               },
               {
                   "field": "test number",
                   "name": "test number name",
                   "width": "100px",
                   "sortable": true
               },
               {
                   "field": "testName",
                   "name": "testNamename",
                   "width": "200px",
                   "sortable": true
               },
           ]
       ]
   },
```

You can see, that JSON parameters are in array, which is in array. I would like to convert this into swagger yaml syntax.
I've tried to write something like:

```
definitions:
  columns:
    type: object
  cells:
    type: array
    items: {
      type: array
      items: {
      properties: 
        field: 
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
        width:
          type: string
        sortable:
          type: boolean
      }
    }
```

But on the second items I received error message of 'missed comma between the flow collection entries'. Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [swagger docs for array data types](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#array) it should look like this:

```
definitions:
  cells:
    type: array
    items:
      type: array
      items: 
        type: object
        properties: 
          field: 
            type: string
          name:
            type: string
          width:
            type: string
          sortable:
            type: boolean
```